# Begin:click not working in Aframe v 0.8.0

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to rotate an object on click and I'm using cursor listener to catch the touch event.

Currently I'm using [animation-component.js](https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@%5E4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js) for animating the object. However, even though im able to animate the button with loop: true but begin:click is not working

```
<a-entity cursor-listener id="butt"
position="-.0.4  -0.1 0.5"
obj-model="obj: #but"
scale="1 1 1"
rotation="0 0 0"
animation__rotate="begin:click; property: rotation; to: 0 360 0 "
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the API. There is no `begin` property.

https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation#api

There is a `startEvents` property.